# nginx suddenly trying to bind on the wrong port

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I'm running on a server that has Apache on port 80. I also have nginx installed, and just one conf file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` which has `listen 8888;` specified. This works perfectly fine.

Now, I added a second conf file for a different vhost within `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, listening on port 7979. When I run `sudo service nginx restart`, I get:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
nginx.
```

Nowhere in any file within `/etc/nginx` is port 80 mentioned! And the only reason I used a different port (7979) is because if both vhosts had port 8888, one would simply redirect to the other, even though they have different `server_name` values.

What's going on here?

Comment: Probably you have server block without `listen` directive. In that case nginx defaults to `listen 80;`. Usually there is on in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ah man, caught again by a missing semicolon! If you post an answer, I'll give you the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

do this and i'm sure you'll find the answer

```
cd /etc/nginx
grep -r 80 *
```

Sometimes if you do something like delete the default vhost and then upgrade it re-installs it back and that uses port 80

So if nginx isn't using it find what is

```
fuser 80/tcp
```

That will list the any pid using port 80.. then you can grep for it

```
ps aux | grep pid#
```

Comment: Already thought of that. No trace of 80.

Comment: see my edit for more info

Comment: I know Apache is running on port 80. That's not the problem though. The issue is that nowhere in nginx's conf files is port 80 mentioned. There are two `listen` directives, `listen 8888` and `listen 7979`.

Comment: Try adding the `-w` option to `grep` to match 80 and not 8000.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server block without a listen directive, Nginx will default to 80.

source: [Server Fault: Nginx tries to run on port 80 but the configs have been removed](https://serverfault.com/a/919300/329496)